# merge deletes and adds wrong files

Tags: git, merge, branch, branching-and-merging, tortoisegit

Before you begin spewing git commands, I use Windows 7-64bit with TortoiseGit (currently v1.7.11.3) exclusively as I am new to Git.

My DEV branch is older than current remote master and I update DEV, and resolve conflicts.
DEV branch has pushed commits to remote DEV branch, thus `rebase` is not possible - as I understand it.

Why does this behaviour happen and how can I avoid it ?

1. `Checkout master` (switch to local master)
2. `Pull origin master` (No conflicts)
3. `Checkout DEV` (switch to dev branch)
4. `Merge master` (apply local master changes into local DEV branch)
5. Fix conflicts and `commit` modified files (both auto-merged and fixed conflict files)

When I open the `log` then I see "parent 1" files as in the commit window AND "parent 2" files, which werent shown. Here is the odd part, files that the (local/remote is same) master had *deleted* are now **added** and new files are **deleted**.
Additionally, "parent 2" files did not produce any conflicts despite some **should**!

The new/deleted files work the opposite of what I expected. Why is that ?
If a file is new in master and I merge into DEV branch, then I expect it to exist after the merge.
My guess is that DEV branch is considered primary, and not the branch (master) I merge into DEV.

I do not have the option to use `Revert` to re-create deleted files (those that are actually new in master).

Comment: Is it possible that at some stage you have reverted a merge? If so then you will find that re-merging will cause you this kind of problem, you will need to revert the revert. (not making this an answer, as I am making a possible assumption about what you may have done)

Comment: DEV branch have not previously been merged with master, so no reverted merge.

Comment: There's a reason why you're expected to speak console commands: it's less ambiguous than describing UI actions in prose, and would let you create a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) to let us reproduce your problem. I'm all for IDEs and GUI tools, but restricting yourself to them makes it harder to describe your problems *precisely*.

Comment: @millimoose what do you find _confusing_, or not clarified enough, about my question ? Look closely and you'll see that I put git commands in code tags.

Comment: @Kim My point is that it's incomplete. If I init a new repository, and enter those commands, I probably won't get the error you're describing. (Seeing as the repository will be empty.) I'd have to add some files and create conflicting changes and add and remove them and I'd still probably just get a merge that does what you and I expect and not the situation you've encountered. The idea is that if you can't describe how to reproduce your problem you haven't really tried to isolate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your merge direction is incorrect as i see it:

You should do:

```
git checkout master
git pull origin master
```

here you have two variants:

1) if you don't want to rewrite dev branch history on the remote then yo got to keep it as is but to do

```
git merge dev # will produce merge commit if not fast-forward
```

2) or if you don't care much about dev branch history

```
git checkout dev
git rebase master # now all commits that happened in dev will be "on top" of master, master will be behind
git checkout master
git merge dev # will result in fast-forward merge without merge commit
```

Now in order to go back to the state before the faulty merge you can just do (if the merge is the last thing you did in dev branch):

```
git checkout dev
git reset --hard HEAD~1
```

Now you can merge properly. In second case the push of dev branch to remote dev most times will be prohibited as non-fast-forward unless you will use -f flag. Hope that helps.

Comment: Option 2) worked, despite log is now out of order. In addition I got an error "unable to create file X", where X is a new file in `master` that `dev` didnt have. Other new files didnt give this error. Due to this error, the `reset --hard` was not run and I had to manually do it.

Comment: What you call out of order is actually normal for rebase. The idea is that you took all commits that happened in dev branch since it diverged from master and then "pretended" that you actually committed them on top of master tip. I.e. moved the base of dev branch.